# jquery validation doesn't work on the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got on my HTML page this form

```
<div class="box fl-panel" id="wrap">
    <form id="sign_in" name="sign_in" class="fm-v" action="" method="post" onsubmit="Javascript:void(0)">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="form_head" colspan="2">Sign In</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="form_username">
                    <label for="user_name" class="fl-label">Email:</label>
                </td>
                <td class="form_username_input">
                    <input id="user_name" name="Email" class="required" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" size="25" autocomplete="false" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="form_submit">
                    <input name="lt" value="*" type="hidden">
                    <input id="submit_sign_in" class="btn-submit" name="submit" accesskey="l" value="Send" tabindex="4" type="submit">
                </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

On the page in `body` tags I set `script` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="login/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="login/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#sign_in").validate({
            rules: {
                user_name: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                user_name: "Wrong email"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

With `jquery validation` plugin.
However when I click on the button `Send` - nothing happened.
There are not in browser console either. 
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Validate plugin's `.validate()` method uses the `name` attribute, NOT the `id`.

```
rules: {
    user_name: "required"  // <- "user_name" must be the NAME attribute
},
messages: {
    user_name: "Wrong email"  // <- "user_name" must be the NAME attribute
},
```

You do not need `class="required"` within the `input` since you've already declared the `required` rule within the `.validate()` method.

**HTML**

```
<input id="user_name" name="user_name" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" size="25" autocomplete="false" type="text">
```

---

Also, your `submitHandler` is superfluous...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

That is already the default behavior so there is no reason to specify it.  In other words, you can remove the `submitHandler` entirely.

Once you change your `name` attribute into `user_name`, this would be the working code...

```
$(function(){
    $("#sign_in").validate({
        rules: {
            user_name: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            user_name: "Wrong email"
        }
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/vupdnd34/**